# test self invoked function with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have anonymous function that makes a fetch call.

```
 fetch(ep)
        .then((response) => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    return;
                }
                response.json().then((data) => {
                   *ADD ELEMENTS TO DOM*
           
                }).catch((err) => {});
            }
        )
```

how can I call expect on time after fetch call return? or is there an option to call the function that adds elements to DOM only? (when using require it calls self invoked)

Comment: Is this your whole app? If so, just await the `fetch` promise chain and assert on it. You can use `.resolves()` as described in [Testing Asynchronous Code](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous). If it's not your whole app (for example, this is part of a `useEffect` in a React component), more context is necessary to know how this code fits into your test suite.

Comment: What do you want to `expect` in your test? What does the fetch callback do? And most importantly: how are you going to run this in a unit test?

Comment: The simple solution: just change it into a named function that returns the promise and which you export, so you can call it and wait for the result in your test. This is what testability is about.

Comment: @ggorlen this function call other function that render some elements to DOM. vanilla JS

Comment: @Bergi this function calls other function and generate element to DOM. I'm checking the elements created